# Error in Laravel Installation

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I already installed laravel with composer create-project, when i deleted the old installation directory and reinstalled it.
Second time it throw an error like this:
`[Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]
  The contents of http://packagist.org/p/doctrine/dbal$d904339843d0d66d194f72
  4e7543073f5fb46ee97d2852bdc0ae96f2cd5cba38.json do not match its signature.
   This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer again and report this if you think it is a mistake.`

Can anybody help me with this error. I am not a master in composer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find [this article](http://vijayan.tomrain.com/solution-for-repository-security-exception-issue-occuring-while-laravel-installation/) quite helpful for solving your issue.

To quote the article:

> When you run the command for downloading laravel installer, the
>   command creates a composer.json file in
>   \Users(XXX)\AppData\Roaming\Composer path. It loads laravel/installer
>   but fails to load Packagist repository (Which is responsible for
>   downloading all laravel dependency modules ).
>
> This error occures when composer do not find packagist repository.

To fix the issue you just need to add the below code in to the `composer.json` file:

```
"repositories": {
"packagist": { "url": "https://packagist.org", "type": "composer" }
}
```

You can find the path for the `composer.json` file as part of the error you get in your terminal window.

Comment: Also make sure you are installing it correctly like so `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-project --prefer-dist`

Comment: Thanks James, I also tried that way but it can only be downloaded with laravel installer, so i reset my windows now it's working better

Answer (score 0):

Update the composer to the latest version by running

```
composer self-update
```

This solved my issue.